# Onepage checkout not working after upgrade

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout, onepage-checkout, magento-community

I upgraded my site from Magento 1.7 to 1.8 but the onepage checkout is not working.I can never go to shipping method step.the continue button does nothing. I tried by modifying info.phtml and payment.phtml but no success. I have gone through the previous answers of same question and i tried everything. So THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE QUESTION.

Comment: are you sure this not a form key issue?

Comment: @MTM Yes i checked the info.phtml file. and the review object is as follow:
review = new Review('<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder', array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())) ?>', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', $('checkout-agreements'));

Is there any other file to check?

Comment: any clues in log file?

Comment: @MTM:Nope no clues. I observed the requests and came to know that the GET request after POST/SaveBilling is not fetched.

Comment: @MTM : so the last request is POST which should be GET i think.

Comment: saveBilling request should be POST, if it is GET, it will not work.

Comment: @MTM SaveBilling is POST but there is no request after that.

Comment: Were the checkout related JS files also updated?

Comment: @MTM: Yes i have not modified any checkout related JS files.

Comment: edit the opcheckout.js file from `skin/frontend/base/default/js/` and on line 290 approx. you will find the Billing Class, try to alert msgs in nextStep function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15880/discussion-between-vishal-and-mtm).

Answer (score 2):

Please check the file `app/design/frontend/your package/ your theme / template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml` and check if the id `checkout-shipping-method-load` exists. if not, please update the file with the new version. Additionally you may also check all the checkout related files if their codes are updated.

Comment: I found the solution. Everything was correct. But i had one extension that was overriding shipping method .I disabled the extension and it works.

Comment: you can live with that module if its really required, as you know the reason of not working now.